# How do I use Vite and Jest with IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, jestjs, vite

I am trying to run a Jest integration test from Intellij. I right click and say run it tries to run but then I get...

> /bin/sh: vite: command not found

I tried adding this to the env vars in the Intellij Run Dialog....

> PATH=$PATH:/my/dir/node_modules/.bin

But then I get...

```
env: node: No such file or directory
node:events:371
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn pgrep ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn pgrep',
  path: 'pgrep',
  spawnargs: [ '-P', 6190 ]
}
```

I can confirm that `vite` is in `/my/dir/node_modules/.bin` and `npx vite` works from terminal. **Vite is not (nor will I) installed globally**

Comment: For the "command not found" error, a more general solution is to add `/my/dir/node_modules/.bin` to your PATH so that it is available in the UI process. For Unix/Linux see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81243/how-do-i-set-the-path-or-other-environment-variables-so-that-x-apps-can-access-i. I imagine MacOS is similar.

Comment: How do you propose doing that because as I said I tried that above do you think my approach was wrong @Code-Apprentice; Hence the second error

Comment: "How do you propose doing that..." I mean I gave a link that shows exactly how to do it. "I said I tried that above " You say you added to the PATH in the run config, but you didn't say anything about pam_env or another more general solution.

Comment: "do you think my approach was wrong" No, I'm not saying that it is wrong exactly. The problem is that you will have to edit the PATH in every run config or add it to a run config template. I am suggesting a more general and permanent solution to that part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using Puppeteer to run integration tests in the browser. Adding npm here...

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  server: {
    command: `npx vite --port 8080 --mode ${process.env.ENV_MODE || "development"}`,
    port: 8080,
    launchTimeout: 10000,
  },
};
```

Notice was `vite --port 8080` now `npx vite --port 8080`

This may not work with some older versions of NPM that don't include npx (don't remember version but think it is behind LTS).